# How to enable input to be a fixed text

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I have the following line to output the following value:

```
<div id = "NameA" style ="display:none">
<p><input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" title="Name" value="NameA"  class="leftCol required validateInput" tabindex="8"/></p>
</div>
```

I am wondering how am I able to make the following text "NameA" as a fixed text, to prevent users from manipulating the text.

Furthermore, the following input tag is a view and I will need to post the following value to the controller - action.php. Hence, I realise that I am unable to use `disabled = 'disabled'` as this will render the view invisible and unable to POST to the controller from View.

Hence how am I able to make the text fixed yet able to POST is over to the controller

Comment: Is there a reason why these have to be input fields? otherwise I would use  labels. and if it's fixed text that will be sent to controller, i'd duplicate the contents in input hidden fields (or just handle it in you code if you know the fixed text in advance).

Comment: @RubenVerschueren Thanks that is a good suggestion too. more effective way of coding

Comment: you are welcome. And sorry about all the spelling mistakes, I was in a hurry ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the readonly tag, like so (see very end of the tag)

```
<input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" title="Name" value="NameA" class="leftCol required validateInput" tabindex="8" readonly />
```

**Reference**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-readonly

Comment: Not sure why you wrapped in a hidden div (display: none) though.

Comment: i wrap it in display:none is because I have conditinal checks depending on user selection in the select list. Hence, If user were to choose option A, the rest of the block should not be showing, etc.

Comment: @Kaido - Thanks! I didn't know that.